# Extremely poor performance with Tableau + Spark + Cassandra

Tags: performance, apache-spark, cassandra, tableau-api, datastax-enterprise

Currently I am in the process of investigating the possibility of using Cassandra in combination with Spark and Tableau for data analysis. However, the performance that I am currently experiencing with this setup is so poor that I cannot imagine using it for production purposes. As I am reading about how great the performance of the combination of Cassandra + Spark must be, I am obviously doing something wrong, yet I cannot find out what.

My test data:

- All data is stored on a single node
- Queries are performed on a single table with 50MB (interval data)
- Columns used in selection criteria have an index on it

My test setup:

- MacBook 2015, 1.1 GHz, 8GB memory, SSD, OS X El Capitan
- Virtual Box, 4GB memory, Ubuntu 14.04
- Single node wit Datastax Enterprise 4.8.4:

  - Apache Cassandra 2.1.12.1046
  - Apache Spark 1.4.2.2
  - Spark Connector 1.4.1
  - Apache Thrift 0.9.3
  - Hive Connector 0.2.11
- Tableau (Connected through ODBC)

Findings:

- When a change in Tableau requires loading data from the database, it takes anywhere between 40s and 1.4 mins. to retrieve the data (which is basically unworkable)
- When I use Tableau in combination with Oracle instead of Cassandra + Spark, but on the same virtual box, I get the results almost instantaneously

Here is the table definition used for the queries:

```
CREATE TABLE key.activity (
    interval timestamp,
    id bigint,
    activity_name text,
    begin_ts timestamp,
    busy_ms bigint,
    container_code text,
    duration_ms bigint,
    end_location_code text,
    end_ts timestamp,
    pallet_code text,
    src_location_code text,
    start_location_code text,
    success boolean,
    tgt_location_code text,
    transporter_name text,
    PRIMARY KEY (interval, id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"ALL"}'
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}
    AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX activity_activity_name_idx ON key.activity (activity_name);
CREATE INDEX activity_success_idx ON key.activity (success);
CREATE INDEX activity_transporter_name_idx ON key.activity (transporter_name);
```

Here is an example of a query produced by Tableau:

```
INFO  2016-02-10 20:22:21 org.apache.spark.sql.hive.thriftserver.SparkExecuteStatementOperation: Running query 'SELECT CASE WHEN 4 >= 0 THEN SUBSTRING(`activity`.`transporter_name`,1,CAST(4 AS INT)) ELSE NULL END AS `calculation_185421691185008640`,
  AVG(CAST(`activity`.`busy_ms` AS DOUBLE)) AS `avg_busy_ms_ok`,
  CAST((MONTH(`activity`.`interval`) - 1) / 3 + 1 AS BIGINT) AS `qr_interval_ok`,
  `activity`.`transporter_name` AS `transporter_name`,
  YEAR(`activity`.`interval`) AS `yr_interval_ok`
FROM `key`.`activity` `activity`
GROUP BY CASE WHEN 4 >= 0 THEN SUBSTRING(`activity`.`transporter_name`,1,CAST(4 AS INT)) ELSE NULL END,
  CAST((MONTH(`activity`.`interval`) - 1) / 3 + 1 AS BIGINT),
  `activity`.`transporter_name`,
  YEAR(`activity`.`interval`)'
```

Here is an example on statistics of a 52s query:

[Spark statistics on query taken 52 secs. to complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJkVI.png)

I've tried playing around with the partition keys as mentioned in other posts, but did not see a significant difference. I've also tried to enable row caching (Cassandra config + table property), but this also did not have any effect (although perhaps I have overlooked something there).

I would have expected to get at least a factor 10x-20x better performance out of the box, even without fiddling around with all these parameters and I've run out of ideas what to do.

What am I doing wrong? What performance should I expect?

Comment: Can you describe the query?  Is there a join, for example?

Comment: @ChrisGerken thanks for looking at my problem. I just added an example of a query. All queries execute on a single table (so no joins).

Answer (score 2):

Answering your questions will not be easy due to the variables that you do not define in your post. You mention data that is stored on one node, which is fine but you don't describe how you have structured your tables/column families. You also don't mention the cassandra cache hit ratios. You also have to consider Cassandra Compaction, if compaction is running during the heavy read/write operations it will slow things down.

You also appear to have a single SSD in which case you will have the Data directory and commitlogs and cache directories on the same physical drive. Even though it is not a spinning disc you will see degraded performance unless you split the data dir from the commitlogs/cache directories. I saw a 50% increase in performance by splitting the Data dir onto its own physical SSD.

Also, lastly you're running in a VM on a laptop host in Vbox none the less. Your largest bottleneck here is the 1.1 GHz CPU. In my cassandra environments on VMWare while running medium jobs I see almost 99% CPU use across 4 X 2 cores on 16GB RAM. My data dir(s) are on SSD's while my commitlogs and cache directories are on a magnetic HDD. I get good performance, but I tuned my environments to get to this point and I accept the latency my non production environments  provide.

Take a look [HERE](http://www.planetcassandra.org/nosql-performance-benchmarks/) and try to get a better understanding of how Cassandra should be used and how to achieve better performance out of the box. Distributed Systems are just that.. distributed and for a reason. Shared resources that you don't have available on a single machine.

Hope this explains a little more about where you're headed.

**EDIT**

Your table definition looks fine. Are you using the Tableau Spark connector? Your performance problem is likely on the cassandra/Spark side of things.

Take a look at this [article](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/compaction-improvements-in-cassandra-21) which describes a compaction related problem while reading from cache. Basically on cassandra releases prior to 2.1.2 post compaction you now have lost your cache because Cassandra threw the file (and cache) away once the compaction finished. Once you start reading you imediately get a missed cache hit and cassandra then goes back to disc. This is fixed in releases from 2.1.2 onward. Everything else looks normal with respect towards running Spark/Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks! I just added an sql query and the table definition to my question. I ran compaction manually before I performed the queries, after that no data was added/changed/deleted. Everything is running from the same SSD, unfortunately there is no easy way for me to change that, but thanks for the tip. Yes, I realise my hardware is far from optimal, but I am merely trying to determine whether the solution is feasible. Glancing over your link I still find it strange that Oracle returns immediately in the same setup while Spark seems to take forever. Will study your link some more...

Comment: I edited my answer, take a look. especially at the linked article wrt your version of cassandra

Answer (score 0):

While the query time does seem a little high, there's a few things I see that could cause issues.

I noticed you're using a MacBook. Beautiful computer but not ideal for Spark. I believe those are using the dual core Intel M processors. If you go to your Spark Master UI, it'll show you available cores. It might show 4 (to include vCPU's). 
The nature in which you are running this query doesn't allow for a lot of parallelism (if any). You basically don't get the advantages of Spark in this case because you're running in an extremely small VM and you're running on a single node (with limited CPU's). Visualization tools haven't really caught up to Spark yet.

One other thing to keep in mind is that Spark is not designed as an 'adhoc query' tool. You can think of SparkSQL as an abstraction over proper Spark Batch. Comparing it to Oracle, at this scale, wont yield the results you expect. There's a 'minimum' performance threshold that you'll notice with Spark. Once you scale data and nodes far enough, you'll start to see that time to completion and size of data is not linear and as you add more data, the time to process remains relatively flat.

I suggest trying that query in the SparkSQL REPL `dse spark-sql` and see if you get similar times. If you do, then you know that's the best you'll get with your current setup. If Tableau is MUCH slower than the REPL, I'd guess it's something on their end at that point.